# MatLab--How would I generate an n-sided shape wher n >= 4

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, polygon

I'm new to Matlab but I know a bit about programming.

For class, we have been asked to generate a matrix that gives the vertices of a two dimensional n-sided shape where n>=4. Then, generate the vectors to connect the vertices. We were also given a hint: a vector for each segment can be found by adding the vectors drawn from the origin to each of two adjacent vertices.

I know how to create a matrix using A = [1 1; 1 2; 2 2; 2 1] but I'm not sure how to draw the vectors given this or any other matrix.

The plot() function looks promising, but I'm unsure how to use it with the matrix.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Btw, I'm using Matlab 2011a

Comment: Are the requested shapes always regular polygons? For your concern about the function `plot`, it will do the job if you call `plot(A(:,1),A(:,2))`. My advise is to add the first point at the end of your matrix, so that the polygon will be closed.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. I ended up using plot() as Luis suggested since I don't want to fill the polygon.

Comment: If Luis' answer helped you, you should accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. First, this signals to everyone that this question has been solved and second, the person whose answer you accept gets reputation points (you get a couple as well). You might want to go back and revisit your previous questions as well and accept answers there as appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how your matrix represents your shape but you might for example let the x-coordinates of the shape be the first column of your array, then let the y-coordinates be the 2nd column, like:

```
A = [1 1; 1 2; 2 2; 2 1];

x = A(:,1);
y = A(:,2);

fill(x,y,'g');
axis([0 3 0 3]);
axis square;
```

Which in your case plots a square from the matrix A:

[image]

Or construct something a little more complicated like a pentagon:

```
theta = [0:pi/2.5:2*pi];
x = sin(theta);
y = cos(theta);

% your matrix is then:
B(:,1) = x;
B(:,2) = y;
B
figure;fill(x,y,'g');
axis square;
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: you beat me by a second!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to plot the outline with `plot` (not fill the interior with `fill`), just remember you have to repeat the initial point at the end so that the polygonal line is closed:

```
A = [1 1; 1 2; 2 2; 2 1];
B = [A; A(1,:) ]; %// repeat first row at the end
plot(B(:,1),B(:,2))
axis equal %// same scale on both axes
axis([min(x)-.5 max(x)+.5 min(y)-.5 max(y)+.5]) %// larger axes for better display
```

[image]